# oracle how to transfer SQL into member function

Tags: oracle, member-functions

one of my assignment question is:
The method AvgReviewScore() returns the average review score for an album excluding scores from anonymous reviewers, i.e. reviews with null REVIEWER_NAME.

So firstly i wrote SQL:
*(This is oriented database assignment)*

```
select deref(b.album).title 
,round(avg(b2.reviewscore),2)
from album_artist_table b,table(deref(b.album).review) b2
where deref(b.artist).aname like '%Joe%'
and b2.reviewername is not null
group by deref(b.album).title;
```

Can i ask how to translate this sql to member function?

I try to create a type called:AvgReviewScore_type

and then i create type body member function as following:

```
create or replace TYPE BODY ALBUM_TYPE AS                                                                                                            
member function AvgReviewScore return AvgReviewScore_type AS
AVGtable AvgReviewScore_type := AvgReviewScore_type(null,null);
BEGIN

select deref(b.album).title,round(avg(b2.reviewscore),2)
into AVGtable
from album_artist_table b,table(deref(b.album).review) b2
where b2.reviewername is not null
group by deref(b.album).title;
return AVGtable;
END AvgReviewScore;
END;
```

But it doesn't work, is there anybody know about the reason?

Comment: What do you mean with "doesn't work"? Are you having a compilation error or a runtime error? and what error? Try to be as detailed as possible to have good answers

Comment: Are you looking for a function ??? Member function are created with Objects. I cannot see any definition of your object. Can you include that as well.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your question has incomplete information and depending on whatever given see the below example. I hope it would help you.

```
Create type exmpl_type as object ( 
  num number,     
  member function  func(p in number) return number
);
/

create type body exmpl_type as              
  member function func(p in number) 
  return number is 
  begin
    return num/p;
  end func;
end;
/
```